# Quiz: people and hats

Tags: probability, puzzle

I've created this quiz, but I'm not sure if the answer that I've found is correct or not.

Three people meet at a pub, each of them has a blue or a red hat on his\her head. 
Nobody knows the colour of the hat on his head but he\she can see the other people's hat.
Simultaneously each one of them guess the colour of the hat on his\her head. They win if and only if everybody answer correctly, and obviously they can't speak to each other.
They know that the hats where assigned by doing a random permutation of 3 red hats and 3 blue hats (i-th hat to the i-th guy).
Question: consider the case where everybody have a red hat, and provided that they will use the best strategy to win (and that they can count on the fact that everybody will use the best strategy), what will be their answer?

***** SOLUTION ALERT *****

This is my solution:

At a first glace you are probably tempted to say that they should all say "blue" since from the point of view of each of them the probability to have a blue hat is $3/4$.
But what if you really have a blue hat on your head? If this is the case the others will see a red hat and a blue hat and, since they don't have any other clue, the best thing that they could do is to pick at random, and so they guess with probability $1/2$.
So the probability to win if you say "blue" is just $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}*\frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{16}$ whether if you say "red" is $\frac{1}{4}$ because you can count that, if you have a red hat, the others will reason in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose everybody plays your strategy: If you see two colours the same, you guess that colour; otherwise you guess at random. Then the probability of success is just the probability that all colours are the same, which is $\frac1{10}$.

Now suppose that everybody plays my strategy: If I see two colours the same, I guess the *other* colour; otherwise I guess at random. Then the probability of success is $\frac14 \times$ (the probability that all colours are not the same), which is $\frac14 \times \frac9{10} = \frac{9}{40}$. This is more than twice as good as $\frac1{10}$.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But why $1/10$? There are $6!$ possible permutations. Since you see that the other two have reds hat you can infer that only $3 * 2 * 4!=144$ permutations are possible. And of those $(3!)^2=36$ will lead to a victory if you say "red". This correspond to a $36/144=1/4$ probability of having a red hat.

Comment: Nevermind I've understood where the $1/10$ came from :p. But since there are 144 possible permutations of which 36 are composed of all red hats. If you use my strategy you win in 36 cases. With your solution you win in $108/4$ cases since in the situation RRB, the one that sees the two red whould guess correctly but the other two have $1/2$ chances each of being right.

Comment: If everybody is playing your strategy, and you see two colours the same, then you have been lucky: you have a $\frac14$ chance of winning. But $\frac35$ of the time, you will see two different colours, and then your chance of winning is $0$.

Comment: By the way, where do your 144 and 36 come from?

Comment: Well I've reasoned in this way: since you see two red hats, you have 3 ways to "choose" the first red hat that you see and 2 ways to "choose" the second one, and $4!$ for permuting the remaining hats (so $3*2*4!=144$). Of those only 36 also have a red hat in your position ($3!$ ways to permute the red hats and $3!$ ways to permute the blue ones). 
If you know python I've made a little program to count them: http://pastebin.com/BMLgjiRc
I don't get why my reasoning is wrong.

Comment: You have to consider all $6!=720$ cases when comparing the two strategies, because most of the time you will see two different colours, in which case you are busted (and I'm not). Now read my answer again with this in mind!

Comment: yes now I got it. Thanks!